# Sign out is not working in google login on android

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I'm trying to sign out of google but I'm getting the error

> IllegalStateException Google API Client is not connected yet.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            signOut();
    }
}
private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    tv_username.setText("");
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Well, the error message is more than informative!

Comment: @clearlight sir i could not understand you answer can you give me answer?